# Postgres Select the first event for a user each day between a given time period

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to be able to get the first event for a user for each day between a given time period.

```
select  * from mytable
where eventId='123'and "time">'2020-02-11'  and "time"<'2020-02-14';
```

returns me this

[image: table before]

i would like To return this

[image: table after]

Any suggestions on how to attempt this

**Update:**
I attempted the query and made a few changes based on the suggestion from @Gordon Linoff suggestion `select distinct ("userId", "time"::date) from public.sensorevents t where "eventId" = '1cfb395f-8c05-4df9-8eed-b3e38edd623f' and"time" > '2020-02-11' and "time" < '2020-02-14';`

This returns me the correct amount of rows 21 However i cant see the value
But if i add in the ,value `select distinct ("userId", "time"::date),value from public.sensorevents t where "eventId" = '1cfb395f-8c05-4df9-8eed-b3e38edd623f' and"time" > '2020-02-11' and "time" < '2020-02-14';`

to the query the query doesn't seem to work and return me the 191 rows becuause each value is differnent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to be able to get the first event for a user for each day between a given time period.

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (userid, "time"::date) *
from mytable t
where eventId = 123 and
      "time" > '2020-02-11' and
      "time" < '2020-02-14'
order by userid, "time"::date, "time";
```

Notes:

- Do not use double quotes around column names.  They just make queries harder to write and read.
- Avoid using SQL keywords like `time` as column names.
- I assume `eventId` is a number, so I dropped the single quotes.

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff thanks for the response just running into one issue with that query i am getting SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions for the time param in the first line

Comment: I updated my question with what i have tried any suggest on how to get the value to show for those 21 rows

Comment: @Johnjoe . . . The queries in your question don't have the `order by` clause.

Comment: When i had order by in my query it gave me this error  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions for the time param in the first line @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @Johnjoe . . . That was fixed hours ago.

Comment: Sorry i was doing something else and didn't see the notification that works thanks for the help @Gordon Linoff